# Force "message" on SVN commit?

Tags: svn

1. How can I force a user to type in a description when committing work to a SVN repository?
2. Is it possible to force the user to type in a specific set of text?

I want a developer to always write a description of the changes he / she made, followed by the words: "IAMSURE" on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Have a `pre-commit` hook on the repo that will look for empty message and stop the commit if so.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html